# Generate Html markup in code behind Vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

I am using the following function to dynamically add html div and image tag in code behind using VB.Net.

```
Public Sub GetUserPictures(ByVal gifId As String)

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim user = New FacebookUser
    ds = user.GetUserImagesByUserId(UserID, New Guid(gifId))
    Dim gImg As Integer
    If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            defaultIcons.InnerHtml = ""
            gImg = Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Id"))
            imageContainer.InnerHtml += "<div class='FunnyFace' style='cursor: pointer'><img id='" + Convert.ToString(gImg) + "' src='" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ImagePath") + "' width='86' height='103' onclick = 'SetImage('" + Convert.ToString(gImg) + "');' /></div>"
            'img1.Src = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ImagePath")
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

but when displaying the page on browser the html looks like the following :

```
<div style="cursor: pointer" class="FunnyFace"><img width="86" height="103" 28');'="" onclick="SetImage(" src="/content/images/ID1.png" id="28"></div>
```

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use ```System.Drawing.Image``` objects to add the pictures?

Comment: Actually i want to view the images inside div (imageContainer) and allow the user to click on it to do some action. how can use the System.Drawing.Image to do so ?

Comment: Solved! there was extra single quote when joining the strings. just remove it.